# vim: how to select and replace one word for all its appearance?

Tags: select, vim, replace, mode, words

In a file, I wish to replace all "middle" with "medium", I dont' wish to use

> :%s:middle:medium:g

I wish to

```
1. put the focus on the word of "middle"
2. press 'gd' to high light it, 
3. and then do something to replace all its appearance(multiple places) into "medium".
```

What's more, does vim provide that when I replace a word, while typing, all its locations will display the same change?

How to do this, should I use normal mode or visual mode?

Comment: What's wrong with `:%s/middle/medium/g`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First question

You can use `:help gn`:

```
*                 jump to the next occurence of the word under the cursor
``                jump back
cgnmedium<Esc>    change it to whatever you want
.                 repeat change on next occurrence
.                 repeat change on next occurrence
.                 repeat change on next occurrence
```

You can map it if you want:

```
nnoremap <key> *``cgn
```

### Second question

No but you can google for "multiple cursor vim" if you *really* want such a feature.